# MS Access Data Validation Rules not Running on Form Close

Tags: ms-access

I have a data entry form which runs a simple data validation rule on data (which works fine) from the source table. Now if I were to scroll down to skip to the next record with invalid data, I will be prompted to change it just fine.

However my form has a close button using a simple

```
DoCmd.Close
```

operation, and clicking the button means that the user is not prompted to change the data - instead the record is just lost. What am I doing wrong here? It's not that warnings are set to be off, as I've even tried adding

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

before close just in case that was the issue.

Comment: Which event are you using to perform this validation?

Comment: Using the built-in validation rule and validation text in the table, eg:
    Rule: Is Null Or >0.25 And <100
    Text: Please enter a valid case weight in kilograms

Comment: Sounds like the form is allowed to close before the validation takes place? Can you add code before the 'DoCmd.Close' that checks the Dirty flag and then forces the form to move to a new record? That may force the validation to take place (you said it is table driven and not form driven?)

Comment: That sounds promising, could you give me an example please? Never played with form.dirty before

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could try adding the validation in the Form's BeforeUpdate event and cancel the closing of the Form if it there is a validation error, like this:

```
    Private blnCancelFormClose As Boolean

    Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
        Dim dblWeight As Double

        dblWeight = Nz(Me.Weight)

        If (dblWeight = 0) Or (dblWeight > 0.25 And dblWeight < 100) Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid case weight in kilograms!", vbExclamation, Me.Caption
            Me.Weight.SetFocus
            blnCancelFormClose = True
            Cancel = True
        Else
            blnCancelFormClose = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)    
        If blnCancelFormClose = True Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - that certainly seems workable, if a little long-winded (to have to re-enter the validation rules, especially as there are 9 in that table!). Just seems odd that Access would allow the form to ignore the built-in validation in the table!